# Slice A4 paper into different triangles using most possible space

Tags: geometry

I want to cut some triangles from A4 paper. For example, I need 4 small ones, 2 medium triangles and one big (they have different shapec etc.). Is there any good algorithm for this? It should use space most effective for another triangles what i want cut in future.

Comment: There is size, proportions, and quantity to consider for the small/medium/large triangles.  Some of these you can fix, and optimize the others.  As written there is no meaningful answer possible to this question.

Answer (score 2):

How about the below. [image]  All the lines hit the centers of where they go, so the mid-size triangles are contgruent. The small ones are not, though they have the same area.  Is that a problem?

Comment: The four small triangles are not in fact congruent. Two are acute and two obtuse.

Comment: @RahulNarain:  Thanks.  Updated

Answer (score 0):

1. Cut a square of $210\,\textrm{mm}\times210\,\textrm{mm}$, then cut the diagonal and you have two triangles.
2. Divide one of those triangles in half so you have your two medium triangles.
3. From the reminding $210\,\textrm{mm}\times89\,\textrm{mm}$ rectangle, cut two $105\,\textrm{mm}\times89\,\textrm{mm}$ rectangles.
4. From each of these $105\,\textrm{mm}\times89\,\textrm{mm}$ rectangles cut the diagonals and you have the four small triangles.

Decide if this fits any definition of efficiency.